# Can not see any CMS blocks in adminpanel Magento

Tags: magento, magento2

When in magento admin panel I go to

Content -> Elements -> Blocks

I can not find any blocks here.

it Says" you cannot define a correlation name 'store_table' more than once "

[image: you cannot define a correlation name 'store_table' more than once]

Magento Enterprise version = 2.4.3-p3

Answer (score 0):

Reason: In our case this issue was related to the admin user roles. We have changed the admin user role values in table authorization_role. Particularly we change the gws_store_groups value.

Solution: Once clear the cache then log out and login in again.

I hope it will help you and save the time. :)